# tautologies and truth values

Tags: propositional-calculus

I have no idea how to start. really appreciate some help here.

Let P and Q be propositions. A statement S (involving P , Q ) is called a tautology iff for any truth-values of P and Q , the statement S is true. Show that the following statements are tautologies.

(a) (P∧(P⇒Q))⇒Q (Modus Ponen)
(b) (¬Q∧(P⇒Q))⇒¬P (Modus Tollens).
(c) (P∧(¬Q⇒¬P))⇒Q  (Proof by Contradiction).

Comment: Make a truth table.

Comment: Make a truth table. List out all possible combinations of values for P and Q (TT,TF, FT, FF), and show that in every case, the statement given evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $(P\wedge (P\Rightarrow Q))\Rightarrow Q$ is a tautology:
$$ \begin{array}
{|c|c|c|c|c|}  
\hline P &  Q & P\Rightarrow Q  & P\wedge (P\Rightarrow Q)& (P\wedge (P\Rightarrow Q))\Rightarrow Q\\ 
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
\hline 1 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 1\\ 
\hline 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\hline 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\hline
\end{array} $$
To prove that $(\sim Q\wedge(P\Rightarrow Q))\Rightarrow (\sim P)$ is a tautology:
$$ \begin{array}
{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}  
\hline P &  Q & P\Rightarrow Q  & \sim Q& \sim Q\wedge(P\Rightarrow Q) & \sim P & (\sim Q\wedge(P\Rightarrow Q))\Rightarrow (\sim P)\\ 
\hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
\hline 1 & 0 & 0  & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
\hline 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\hline 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
\end{array} $$
To prove that $(P\wedge(\sim Q\Rightarrow(\sim P)))\Rightarrow Q$ is a tautology:
$$ \begin{array}
{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}  
\hline P & Q & \sim P & \sim Q & \sim Q\Rightarrow(\sim P) & P\wedge(\sim Q\Rightarrow(\sim P) & (P\wedge(\sim Q\Rightarrow(\sim P)))\Rightarrow Q\\ 
\hline 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline\end{array} $$
Here you are! I hope everything is clear now, but feel free to ask for additional clarification.